# Issue with jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate() for large list of queries

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am facing an issue with `JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(String[] queries)` method when processing bulk of queries.

The statement is getting executed without any exception but updation is not reflected in database. We are using sybase. The size of list of queries is around 7000+.

Have anyone faced similar issue before?

Comment: How are your transactions configured?

Comment: Have you checked the return int[] value? Did they indicate any row get updated?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the issue. It was very silly coding which was not logged properly. The batchUpdate was called under a try block and in catch it was not logged to logger but system console. The execution thrown exception as one of the queries were malformed.

Comment: Nice work PankajDwivedi. As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. I got the issue. It was very silly coding which was not logged properly. The batchUpdate was called under a try block and in catch it was not logged to logger but system console. The execution thrown exception as one of the queries were malformed.